# Quota for MongoDB for each cPanel user

Tags: mongodb, cpanel

I would like to know how can I allow a quota or a limit for each cPanel user to access MongoDB - I want them to be able to use any quota but it needs to also account as hard drive space.

Answer (score 1):

Officially MongoDB support is still not included in cPanel so I doubt you can set quota for MongoDB from cPanel/WHM. There was a feature request submitted in official cPanel website but this feature is still not included in latest version as of now (cPanel 11.52). Also, I am not able to locate any plugin for cPanel which can help you in this matter.